# I used bootstrap modal and want to move another page after click on submit button which is on modal. I moved but backdrop is still there

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I used following code in angular controller function this function I am calling on modal submit button click. I moved on another page but backdrop is still there. How I can solve this problem.

`$scope.modalSubmitClicked  = function(){
 $('#my-modal').modal('hide');
 $location.path("/mypreferredpage");
}`

Comment: $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Is the problem not that your redirecting when the modal is still busy closing?

Comment: while debugging in script if I will just  do "$('#my-modal').modal('hide')"  this and move to another page it works fine backdrop also will be not there. but in java script I do what ever I wrote above it is not working.